# Issue with changelog display order

Tags: php, sql

First of all, forgive the ugly method. I'm tired and I can't think of another way to do it at the moment.

So, my issue is this: My changelog was working fine until yesterday. I've been fighting with it all night and can't seem to fix it.
It displays everything correctly, until it hits 20/02/2014, then it just repeats it (see screenshot)

Here's my code (again, forgive me)

```
$select = $mtgdb->query("SELECT `timewhen` FROM `changelog` GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(`timewhen`, '%d%m%Y') ORDER BY `timewhen` DESC");
while($row = $mtgdb->fetch_row($select)) {
?><li><?php echo date('d/m/Y', $row['timewhen']);?><ul><?php
    $selectContent = $mtgdb->query("SELECT `content` FROM `changelog` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`timewhen`, '%d%m%Y') = ".date('dmY', $row['timewhen'])." ORDER BY `timewhen` ASC");
    while($row2 = $mtgdb->fetch_row($selectContent)) {
        ?><li><?php echo $mtg->format($row2['content']);?></li><?php
    }
?></ul></li><?php
}
```

Info:
fetch_row() = mysqli_fetch_assoc()

```
function format($str, $dec = 0) {
    return is_numeric($str)? number_format($str, $dec) : stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($str));
}
```

Now, it displays fine, until it hits the issue that I apparently can't explain clearly enough (again, tired, sorry!)

Changelog screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/Hr45QsDe3QB
Database excerpt screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/PCuk0XJ8e6

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `changelog` (
   `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
   `timewhen` bigint(25) not null default '0',
   `content` text not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it myself.
For anyone that wanted to know how. I simply changed the select query

```
$select = $mtgdb->query("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`timewhen`, '%d/%m/%Y') AS `datestamp` FROM `changelog` GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(`timewhen`, '%d%m%Y') ORDER BY `timewhen` DESC");
while($row = $mtgdb->fetch_row($select)) {
    ?><li><?php echo $row['datestamp']; ?><ul><?php
        $selectContent = $mtgdb->query("SELECT `content` FROM `changelog` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`timewhen`, '%d/%m/%Y') = '".$row['datestamp']."' ORDER BY `id` ASC");
        while($row2 = $mtgdb->fetch_row($selectContent)) {
            ?><li><?php echo $mtg->format($row2['content']); ?></li><?php
        }
    ?></ul></li><?php
}
```